# Converting struct to map with reflection: the field value is returned <nil> instead of nil

Tags: go

I need to convert a simple struct to a map, skipping fields with empty values. To do this, I wrote the code:

```
type User struct {
    Name     string    
    Birthday *time.Time 
}

func main() {
    var user = User{
        Name:     "Anna",
        Birthday: nil,
    }

    objValue := reflect.ValueOf(user)
    objType := objValue.Type()

    data := make(map[string]interface{})

    for i := 0; i < objValue.NumField(); i++ {
        field := objType.Field(i)
        value := objValue.Field(i).Interface()

        if value != nil {
            fmt.Println(field.Name, "=", value)
            data[field.Name] = value
        }
    }

}
```

But 'Birthday' field is not ignored, since it has the value not `nil`, but `<nil>`

**Output:**

```
Name = Anna     
Birthday = <nil>
```

I tried using this [library](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure), but there is an [error](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure/issues/334) in it - Time is returned as map[]

```
type User struct {
    Name     string    `mapstructure:",omitempty"`
    Birthday time.Time `mapstructure:",omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var user = User{
        Name:     "Anna",
        Birthday: time.Now(),
    }

    result := map[string]interface{}{}
    err := mapstructure.Decode(user, &result)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result)
}
```

**Output:**

```
map[Birthday:map[] Name:Anna]
```

Is it possible to fix the code somehow so as not to get `<nil>`, or perhaps there is another solution?

Comment: `time.Time` can't be `nil`, did you try using a`*time.Time` with `mapstructure` like you did in the first example? `Birthday` is printed as `<nil>` because you are printing it. If you don't want to do that, skip it when it's `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`IsNil`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.20.4#Value.IsNil) (but make sure to invoke it only on values that *can* be nil):

```golang
for i := 0; i < rv.NumField(); i++ {
    ft := rt.Field(i)
    fv := rv.Field(i)
    if !can_be_nil(fv) || !fv.IsNil() {
        fmt.Println(ft.Name, "=", fv.Interface())
        data[ft.Name] = fv.Interface()
    }
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/0NnjPMrHr0d

---

The `value` variable, which is of type `interface{}`, is not `nil` because it contains information about the wrapped `nil`'s type (i.e., `*time.Time`).

```golang
fmt.Println((*time.Time)(nil) == nil) // true
fmt.Println(interface{}(nil) == nil) // true
fmt.Println(interface{}((*time.Time)(nil)) == nil) // false
```

https://go.dev/play/p/18_cxSrqTNO

See this FAQ entry for more info: https://go.dev/doc/faq#nil_error